# Looping through all the elements of object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an object like this:

```
    myObj = {"id":12,"title":"my title","content":"my content"}
```

I want to loop through all the element of this object to have something like this:

```
    echo " $key ." = ". $value

    result : id = 12
             title = my title
             content = my content
```

but if I loop through my object like this:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
       echo "$key = $value\n";
 }
```

and I got this result :

```
incrementing => 1
exists => 1
wasRecentlyCreated =>
```

How can I get the elements of my object?

Comment: you could use `get_object_vars()` then loop through the resulting array with `$someLoopedValFromArr = $object->{$someLoopedValFromArr}`,

Comment: Confused by question... you got results that are not at all present in `myObj`? Or is this just a bad example of your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code:

```
$myObj = '{"id":12,"title":"my title","content":"my content"}';

$object = json_decode($myObj);

foreach($object as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br>";
};
```

[More information](https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/)

[Try it online](http://www.writephponline.com/)